# QGIS Layout - Map Frame shows only white and is not accessible

Tags: qgis, print-composer, mapping, atlas

I created a working atlas series in the print composer. After some time the map frame is all white and showing no map, even with disabling the atlas preview. It's impossible to access the map frame and all of its attributes in the properties are mostly like "nan". The progress/loading bar is running the entire time but with no result. Adding a new map frame leads to the same issue and is inaccessible after some time.
Is it possible to get the control of the map frames back? I don't have any clue how to do so.

Comment: Have you restarted QGIS? Have you updated your GIS? Have you tried leaving some clunky layers out of the map layout? How do you define "some time"?

Comment: What version of QGIS are you using?

Comment: You might check the geometry of your layers, especially your index layer.  Check your index layer to make sure none of the polygons are out of whack.  If you have dynamic text you might make sure they are correctly written and the attribute values they are based on make sense.

Comment: If you have no background maps perhaps the values of the attribute field are empty. Could you share a screenshot of the print composer and also a screenshot of atlas properties?

Comment: Did you change your project CRS after creating your atlas? If that is the case, revert back to the earlier CRS with which the layout was created.